# PHP - Error installing OAuth

Tags: php, composer-php

I already check out some other posts but none help me.

The error is:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google' not found in
<b>/dir/libs/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php</b> on line
<b>54</b>
<br />
```

I also read that I had to install League with composer. This is my composer.json,

```
 {
     "require": {
         "php": ">=5.5.0",
         "slim/slim": "^3.1",
         "slim/php-view": "^2.0",       
         "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",
         "league/oauth2-client": "^2.2"
     }
 }
```

Comment: error seems clear, what dont you understand about it?

Comment: The thing is why the message 'not found'? As you can see I already added `league` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google provider is not part of the `league/oauth2-client` package. You also need to install the [league/oauth2-google](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google) package.